# Android studio Kotlin Permission is granted but still showing black screen

Tags: android, kotlin

hello l'm working on a program that you start from MainActivity and you choose something from auto complete text view and by pressing a button you intent to MainActivity2 where it should opens the camera. l used a tutorial for runtime permissions and it asks for the camera permission at the Mainctivity then at MainActivity2 it should open the camera preview but while the app shows the permission granted toast message it still shows only black screen(my main language is not english l'm sorry if there are any mistakes)

MainActivity

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.DialogInterface
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
import android.widget.Button
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions
import androidx.core.content.Co
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission
import com.example.myapplication.MainActivity
import com.example.myapplication.R



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val Camerarq = 101
    lateinit var button1: Button
    lateinit var button2: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1)
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2)
        checkOnPermissions(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, "camera", Camerarq)


        val actv = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.autoCompleteTextView)
        val Antibiotics = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Antibiotics)
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
            applicationContext,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            Antibiotics
        )
        actv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)


        val actv2 = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2)
        val microbes = resources.getStringArray(R.array.microbes)
        val arrayAdapter2 = ArrayAdapter(
            applicationContext,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            microbes
        )
        actv2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2)
        button1.setOnClickListener {
            if (actv.text.isNotBlank() && actv2.text.isNotBlank()) {
                val intent1 = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity2::class.java)
                startActivity(intent1)
            } else if (!actv.toString().isBlank() && !actv2.toString().isBlank()) {
                showAlert()
            }
        }


        button2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent1 = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity2::class.java)
            startActivity(intent1)

        }
    }

    fun showAlert() {
        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)

        alertDialog.setTitle("Dikkat!")
            .setMessage("Lütfen tüm boşlukları doldurunuz")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.warning)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("ok", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialoginterface, which ->

                button1.text

            })

        alertDialog.create().show()

    }


    private fun checkOnPermissions(permission: String, name: String, requestCode: Int) {
        when{
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission) -> showDialog(permission, name, requestCode)

            else -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(permission), requestCode)
        }

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        fun innerCheck(name: String){
            if (grantResults.isEmpty() || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "$name permission refused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "$name permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
        when (requestCode) {
            Camerarq -> innerCheck("camera")
        }

    }

    fun showDialog(permission: String, name: String, requestCode: Int){
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

        builder.apply{
            setMessage("permission to access your $name is required to use this app ")
            setTitle("permission required")
            setPositiveButton("ok"){ dialog, which ->
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity, arrayOf(permission), requestCode)
            }
        }
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()

    }
}
```

MainActvity2

```
import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.HandlerThread
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Surface
import android.view.TextureView
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission

class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {


    lateinit var handler: Handler
    lateinit var handlerThread: Thread
    lateinit var TextureView1: TextureView
    lateinit var Button3: Button
    lateinit var cameraManager: CameraManager
    lateinit var cameraCaptureSeasion: CameraCaptureSession
    lateinit var CaptureRequest: CaptureRequest
    lateinit var cameraDevice: CameraDevice


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)


        cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        Button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3)
        TextureView1 = findViewById(R.id.textureView1)
        handlerThread = HandlerThread("videoThread")
        handlerThread.start()
        handler = Handler((handlerThread as HandlerThread).looper)

        TextureView1.surfaceTextureListener = object : TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
            override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(
                surface: SurfaceTexture,
                width: Int,
                height: Int
            ) {
                open_camera()

            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(
                surface: SurfaceTexture,
                width: Int,
                height: Int
            ) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(surface: SurfaceTexture): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(surface: SurfaceTexture) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun open_camera() {
        cameraManager.openCamera(
            cameraManager.cameraIdList[0],
            object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

                override fun onOpened(p0: CameraDevice) {
                    cameraDevice = p0
                    var CapReq = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
                    var surface = Surface(TextureView1.surfaceTexture)
                    CapReq.addTarget(surface)

                    cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
                        listOf(surface),
                        object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                            override fun onConfigured(p0: CameraCaptureSession) {
                                cameraCaptureSeasion = p0
                                cameraCaptureSeasion.setRepeatingRequest(CapReq.build(), null, null)

                            }

                            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {

                            }
                        },
                        handler
                    )
                }

                override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {

                }

                override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {

                }
            },
            handler
        )


    }
}
```